# can someone explain the code

Tags: python

can someone explain the code How it works:
I am not familiar with while loop

```
 line = file.readline()
 L1=[]
 while line != '' and line != '\n':
    line = line[:-1].split()
    L1.append(line)
    line = file.readline()

 return L1
```

and  can I do it with a for loop?
Is it:

```
     for line in file.readline():
          if line !='' and line !='\n':
             line = line[:-1].split()
             L1.append(line)

     return L1
```

Comment: Have you googled for "while loop"?

Comment: Have you googled the usage of "for" loop in python?

Answer (score 4):

1. read one line from file.
2. if the line is empty or `'\n'`, stop.
3. discard the last character (it's usually `'\n'`, `strip()` is better IMO), split by whitespace, then append list.
4. goto step 1.

And the problem with your `for` loop is that it won't stop on empty or `'\n'`

Answer (score 1):

First read this: http://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop
This will explain a while loop to you.

A while loop is a loop which will continue while the conditions are true,

```
x = 0
while x < 10:
  print(x)
  x = x + 1
print("finished")
```

will print out `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 finished` when x==10 the loop will end and the word 'finished' will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly. The first example will *stop* looping when it reads a line matching `''` or `'\n'`. You could simplify it to this:

```
from itertools import takewhile
[x.strip() for x in takewhile(lambda x: x not in ['', '\n'], file.readlines())]
```

This will store every line of the file, until it finds a `''` or `'\n`, in a new array.

Comment: he doesn't understand the code _he_ has posted. Do you think he will understand the code you just posted? Single liner?

Comment: Probably not, but someone who finds this page might find it useful, possibly even the OP some time in the future. It can't hurt to be exposed.

Comment: I find it useful, because I like to see examples for features of the language, but it's true that it doesn't solve the problem "I don't understand the code".